# How calculate an AAC audio file size?

Tags: java, android, audio, size, aac

I need take the byte array index to a specific millisecond of an AAC audio file, what i think be the same of the audio size to that millisecond.
by now i'm doing this:

```
private static int byteIndexByMilliseconds(int milliSecond) {
    int index = BITS_PER_SAMPLE * milliSecond / 8;

    return index;
}
```

this doesn't work with perfect precision, i need the better precision possible. Did Someone did something like this before that can help me? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the compressed data in the file? Since you don't know how well the compression worked on this particular audio the only way to find positions is to decompress the file.

Comment: yeah, of course, are you right, now i have to see how make this in Android, thankyou